# save result of UNION query in local variable in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, union

In my MySQL Stoared Procedure I want to store result of bellow query into local variables.

MySQL SP

```
BEGIN
Declare temp_ID bigint;
Declare temp_teamName Text;
(select ID,team1 from tbl_tournament_matches where leveID = 1 and tournamentID = 91 and matchType = 'L')
UNION
(select ID,team1 from tbl_tournament_matches where leveID = 2 and tournamentID = 91 and looserTeam is not null)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
select temp_ID, temp_teamName;
END;
```

How can I pass result of query into local variable?
note : above SP will return only 1 row.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this without having to store the value into a variable.

```
SELECT * FROM(

select ID,team1 from tbl_tournament_matches where leveID = 1 and tournamentID = 91 and matchType = 'L'

UNION 

select ID,team1 from tbl_tournament_matches where leveID = 2 and tournamentID = 91 and looserTeam is not null
) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

But, if you want to store a value for later use, you can use the INTO keyword:

```
 SELECT id, data INTO @x, @y FROM test.t1 LIMIT 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: When I use the above example I get an error saying "Every derived table must have its own alias" so at the end of the main select statement and before ORDER BY I put AS tmp_table and solved the issue